# Make child div fill parent div with scroll

Tags: css, flexbox

I am having problems with flexbox layout parenting a child control.

```css
html, body, .frame{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.frame{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.header{
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 40px;
}
.body-outer{
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.body-inner{
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1;
}
.big-text{
  height: 2000px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="body-outer">
      <div>subheader</div>
      <div class="body-inner>">
        <div class="big-text">big text</div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
```

The 'body-inner' div is meant to fill the remaining space with flex: 1 and the 'big-text' is supposed to fill the whole space of 'body-inner' without expanding it but showing scroll bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `overflow` applied to the content. It should be applied to the container that will be overflowed.

Also, you need a fixed height, so that the `overflow` property has something to overflow.

Try this:

```css
.frame {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 40px;
}

.body-outer {
  height: calc(100vh - 40px); /* new */
  background-color: green;
  /* flex: 1; */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.body-inner {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto; /* moved here */
}

.big-text {
  height: 2000px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  /* overflow: auto; */
  margin: 5px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="body-outer">
    <div>subheader</div>
    <div class="body-inner">
      <div class="big-text">big text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That brought me on the right track, thanks. It seems that I cannot use flex 1 together with overflow since i need a definite height.